# I am generating images that will be continuously into a folder as an output. My goal is to change the output location to another computer

Tags: python

I am working on some python code and I am generating images that will be continuously into a folder as an output. My goal is to change the output location to a folder on another computer and be able to add images into it using a python script.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: How do I change the output location to another computer?

Answer (score 1):

Is the remote computer accessible over SMB? In that case, you should be able to open it with something like the following:

```
open("//Server/Folder/AnotherFolder/Writeme.txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a programming question than a system architecure question, but I will give you some ideas:

1. Use Amazon S3 and the `boto3` library for python.  One line of code and you will have the images uploaded to Amazon S3 for use anywhere.
2. Setup SSH keys between the systems and use `subprocess` to initiate an `scp` call to copy the image.
3. Setup a network share so you have a local path on the original computer that can write to the other.

---

Despite how great python is, you can't just put stuff on other computers without a agreed upon protocol, server, and/or network setup.

I recommend you use a cloud provider like Amazon S3.

Comment: The images can not be uploaded into a cloud. The idea is to be able to run a script that stores images into a folder which will be accessible by another computer. Hence, storred in a folder on the secondary computer. Is there any way you could give an example of how to do this with your second example given with SSH keys?

Comment: Can you give a little more info about what operating system, networking proximity, and other relevant details?